# geom bar comapre years per month

Tags: r

I have 2 datas, one for 2020 and the other for 2019. Each is divided into 5 groups when each month has its own data.
I want to create a graph that compares each month for each group between the figure in 2020 and the figure in 2019.

the data for 2020 was like that-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbn1p.png)

and the data for 2019 was the same.

I combine the 2 datas to that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EMAW.png)

The problem is that all the graphs I looked at on the internet have either one column of values or no division into months.
How can you create one graph that compares each month between 2019 and 2020?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you make a reproducible example you are more likely to get assistance. That would include using dput to paste the data instead of a picture. Also showing the code you have used so far will give people an opportunity to help you at a common level.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# bring table in long format
longerTable <- tibble(month = 1:12, value_2020 = rnorm(12), value_2019=rnorm(12)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("value"), names_to="year", values_to="value")

# plot with ggplot.
ggplot(longerTable, aes(x=month, y=value, fill=year)) + 
  # stat = identity -> plot numbers as they are
  # position = dodge -> show bars next to each other
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @OfirYosef you are welcome, please consider to accept the answer as solution